# How to re-use HTML component wrapper in a sequence of child components?

Tags: reactjs, components, children, code-reuse

I have what I thought would be a very simple question about reusing html wrappers for components.  But I'm not sure what the 'proper' way to do it is.

I want to render a series of components reusing the same (complex) html wrapper for each of them. Then rendering the a set of different child components inside that wrapper.

```
(render 10 of these:)
<div i start>
    <div start reusable wrapper>

        <child component - one of ten different components, one after the other>

    <div end reusable wrapper

<div i end>
```

I just need a high level suggestion.  I feel like everything I think of is 'hacking it'.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you provide a more concrete example?

Answer (score 2):

```
const Layout = props => (
  <div whateverattributes>
    <div whateverotherattributes>
      {props.children}
    </div>
   </div>
);
```

Then

```
<Layout>
  <ChildComponent />
</Layout>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was something simple and I was newb-ing.  :)